# How to know which tags to use in scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Is there any logic which tags should be used in scraping?
Right now I'm just doing "trial-and-error" on different tag variations to see which works. It takes a lot of time and is really frustrating. I can't understand the logic as to why some tags work and some dont. For example, the code below works fine:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IWDA.AS?p=IWDA.AS&.tsrc=fin-srch')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


test1 = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'app'})
print(test1)
```

However, just a slight change to the code and the result is "None":

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IWDA.AS?p=IWDA.AS&.tsrc=fin-srch')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

test2 = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'YDC-Lead-Stack-Composite'})
print(test2)
```

Is there any logical explanation why the first example (test1) returns values and why the second example (test2) doesn't return any value?

Is there an efficient way to know which tags will work?

[image: HTML]

Comment: Hello, what is the part of the page you want to scrap ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're trying to scrape a react webapp which will be impossible via the usual web scraping methods.
If you view the raw source (before the scripts are loaded, you'll find that the app is not loaded (as it runs in javascript and fetches the data).

[image: raw source]

There are two options here:

1. Find out if there is an API you can query (instead of scraping)
2. Load the page in a browser and use selenium to scrape (see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)